# What is the syntax in python to run a oracle query, and have the results inserted into a new oracle table?

Tags: python, database, oracle

I am new at python, and am still unsure of all the ins and outs of it.  I have managed to create a new table in oracle using python, but now I want to be able to insert 3 attributes from a previously created table.

so basically, my query is currently something simple like:

```
select attribute1, attribute2, attribute 3 from mytable where qc_code = 'F';
```

the new table i created also has attribute1, attribute2, attribute 3 as the only attributes in the table.

sorry if this question isn't clear; i guess the main point is, how do i insert results from a query into another table using python.

The reason im using python, is because i plan to add multiple queries, but since im still learning, im just trying to get this one to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Don't get the results into python and then put them back into the database as that is inefficient. Just use an `INSERT ... SELECT` statement and do all the processing in the database:

```sql
INSERT INTO other_table (attribute1, attribute2, attribute3)
select attribute1,
       attribute2,
       attribute3
from   mytable
where  qc_code = 'F';
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation of cx_Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/python/quickstartpythononprem.html). It shows how to insert data and query data. So you want to query first, do some python-magic to the data and finally insert it back into the database.

```py
import cx_Oracle

connection = cx_Oracle.connect(
    user="demopython",
    password="XXXXX",
    dsn="localhost/xepdb1")

print("Successfully connected to Oracle Database")

cursor = connection.cursor()

# Create a table

cursor.execute("""
    begin
        execute immediate 'drop table todoitem';
        exception when others then if sqlcode <> -942 then raise; end if;
    end;""")

cursor.execute("""
    create table todoitem (
        id number generated always as identity,
        description varchar2(4000),
        creation_ts timestamp with time zone default current_timestamp,
        done number(1,0),
        primary key (id))""")

# Insert some data

rows = [ ("Task 1", 0 ),
         ("Task 2", 0 ),
         ("Task 3", 1 ),
         ("Task 4", 0 ),
         ("Task 5", 1 ) ]

cursor.executemany("insert into todoitem (description, done) values(:1, :2)", rows)
print(cursor.rowcount, "Rows Inserted")

connection.commit()

# Now query the rows back
for row in cursor.execute('select description, done from todoitem'):
    if (row[1]):
        print(row[0], "is done")
    else:
        print(row[0], "is NOT done")
```